# Exit code 127 in cygwin64

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, package-management, exit-code

After years without problems, suddenly several programs in my installation of [cygwin64](https://www.cygwin.com/) on 64-bit Windows 7 Professional are failing to run, and instead appear to exit immediately with **code 127,** which [usually means "command not found" in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1763156/782129).  In particular, programs like `vim`, `emacs`, and even `clear` exhibit this behavior, while others like `vi`, `echo`, `touch`, and `date` seem to operate normally.

At first, I figured something might have gone wrong with a previous round of package updates, so I ran another update using cygwin setup's [command-line interface](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.cli), but it didn't seem to help.

From what I can tell, the affected programs don't work at all.  Not even `--version` flags to the program work, which makes me think that there may be something wrong with cygwin itself or a common dependency:

```
$ vim --version
$ echo $?
127
```

(I can provide specific version numbers for various packages if it will help, but since this problem existed both before and after the most recent updates, I doubt it matters much.)

I double-checked my PATH variable, and it begins with `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:`, as expected.  Is there perhaps some new dependency in these programs that isn't being properly resolved by cygwin's package manager or which may not have been automatically added to my PATH?

Am I missing something else obvious?

Comment: Did you check your PATH variable?

Comment: @mdpc: Yes, I should have mentioned that.  It is 2096 bytes long, and begins with `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin`, as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `clear` was the culprit.  I diagnosed this by trying to run it with its full path:

```
$ /usr/bin/clear
$ echo $?
127
```

I then looked inside `/usr/bin` and found that **`clear` was somehow missing altogether.**  So, using cygwin's GUI setup, I forced a fresh reinstall of `ncurses`, the package which contains `clear`, and everything seems to be in working order now.

It stands to reason that `vim` and `emacs` both make use of `clear`, hence the problems cascaded to those programs, too.

Answer (score 5):

The exact same thing happened to me after I did a cygwin update, vim won't start, code 127.  Adding clear.exe did nothing.

`strace vim +q` gave sigalstack could not be located in the dll cygwin1.dll
The kind folks at the cygwin mailing list said my update probably did not complete becuase i did not close all my cygwin processes.  Indeed I had sshd and cygrunsrv going, I killed those, and reinstalled cygwin base (go into setup and manually select reinstall cygwin base) this fixed everything.  Good luck friends

Comment: This worked for me after ssh stopped working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that arrives here from Google - I had an experience where programs were exiting with error code 127 on Cygwin (gcc in particular).

The problem turned out to be I installed into a path with a space in it.

If you install using the GUI, it warns you about this. I installed from the command line and no such warning stopped me from doing the install.